# Has anyone used transaction control in custom button using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, custom-button, ajax

I have requirement to use multiple DML statements in my custom button and I want to rollback the changes if DML fails as we do in Apex.

I couldn't find any method in Ajax guide.

Comment: Could you provide more detail around your assignment? Namely, why the need to do this work through ajax in the button, instead of just having the button navigate you to a page with an automatic action defined which would allow you to do the work in Apex.

Comment: I thought of the same but this code was written long back I didn't want to move all of this into an apex method. Looks like I have to move it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there wasn't any methods in AJAX toolkit to provide this transaction control just like in Apex.

When we had a similar requirement, we wrote JavaScript button which calls Apex method written in webservice class which handles the transaction control.

Update:

As stated in comment to have a button which takes user to a VF page which have an action method doing the transaction control is pretty easy way. But some clients are reluctant to have their users navigating through a blank page. That's why we went with JavaScript button method.